# Array to pointer vs 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

`char *string1[20] = { "hello", "world" };`

1. So based on my code, we can do this with array of pointer, but with single array, we can't do this. Why we can't assign multiple string to 1d array without pointer?
2. In 1d array, we are able to access every single of char in string. 
   So, is it possible to access a single value of string1 (example I want to access 'o' in "world")?

Comment: Well, you can always assign the nth element in your array to a normal pointer to char, which in turn can be indexed like any C string: `char *worldP = string1[1]; printf("2nd char in worldP: %c\n", worldP[1]);`

Comment: Your question is not clear, especially part 1; please improve it.

Comment: actually, i'm trying to access char in string1....example i want to access 'o' in "world".......not trying to assign......so is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the string literals `"hello"` and `"world"` is an array of `char`, so

```
char string1[20] = { "hello", "world" };
```

wouldn't work; it's the same as writing

```
int foo = { 1, 2 };
```

you're trying to store 2 things into 1 object.

You can do a couple of different things:

- You can store *one* of the strings to `string1`:

  ```
  char string1[20] = "hello"; // will copy the *contents* of "hello" into string1
  ```

  You can *concatenate* the two string literals into a single string and store *that* in `string1`:

  ```
  char string1[20] = "hello" " " "world"; // preprocessor concatenates adjacent string literals into a single string
  ```

  You can declare `string1` as a 2D array of `char`:

  ```
  char string1[2][20] = { "hello", "world" }; // copies contents of "hello" to string1[0] and "world" to string1[1]
  ```

With the current declaration of `string1`, you can access individual characters of each string literal:

```
char *string1[20] = { "hello", "world" };
...
putchar( string1[1][1] ); // writes 'o' to standard output
```

Note that in this case you're storing pointers to string literals in `string1`, not copies of the strings themselves.  String literals are not modifiable (attempting to do so invokes undefined behavior); if you want to be able to modify the string contents, use the 2D array declaration I showed above.

**Edit**

Answering question here instead of the comments, because it won't fit there.

`"hello"` and `"world"` are string literals; they are stored as arrays of `char` such that they are allocated when the program starts up and released when the program exits.  Both literals are expressions of type "6-element array of `char`" (5 letters plus the 0 terminator).

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "`N`-element of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Examples:

```
char arr[6] = "hello";
```

This allocates `arr` as a 6-element array of `char` and copies the string `"hello"` to it; it's identical to writing

```
char arr[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

Since the array expression `"hello"` is being used to initialize another array of `char`, it is not converted to a pointer expression.

```
char *p = "world"
```

In this case, this allocates `p` as a pointer to `char`; it stores the *address* of a single `char` object.  Since the string literal `"goodbye"` is not the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first character in the string.

```
char *parr[2] = { "hello", "world" };
```

only allocates enough space two store two pointers to `char`, not two character arrays.

If we look at a memory map of all of the above, we get something that looks like this (addresses are pulled out of thin air and don't represent any real world platform; using 16-bit addresses just to save space):

```
Item            Address       00  01  02  03
----            -------       --  --  --  --
"hello"         0x8000        'h' 'e' 'l' 'l'
"world"         0x8004        'o'  0  'w' 'o'
                0x8008        'r' 'l' 'd'  0   
                ...
arr             0xff00        'h' 'e' 'l' 'l'
                0xff04        'o'  0  ??  ??
p               0xff08        08  06  ??  ??
parr            0xff0c        08  00  08  06
```

The string literal `"hello"` is storead at address `0x8000`, while `"world"` is stored at address `0x8006`.  The character array `arr` is stored at address `0xff00` and contains a *copy* of the string `"hello"`.  The pointer `p` is stored at address `0xff08` and stores the *address* of the first character of the string literal `"world"`.  You should be able to figure out `parr` (which is pretty much what your original code snippet is doing).

Comment: I dont really understand with your statement "storing pointer  to string literals".
can you explain further?

Comment: so, it is mean that i actually store the address of pointer to string literals as string value not the value of string literals itself, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use it as a 2D array, because of pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *str[20] = {"hello", "world"};

    printf("%c\n", str[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to access it with deferencing the str?

Comment: @KevinMogi You mean, without using the index operator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can a access it directly, if you previously know the size of the inner arrays, you can access with the usual array arithmetic.

```
string1[1][1] == 'o'
```